# Computing the Maximum in an MxM Matrix

Tags: algorithms

I have an MxN matrix where each element contains a positive numeric value.

I need to find those elements in the matrix that add up to the "maximum value". The caveat is that each row and column can be used *at most once* in calculating the total.

I have a brute force algorithm for doing this bit it's ugly. I was wondering if there is a well-known algorithm for accomplishing this.

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is known as [maximum weighted bipartite matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#In_weighted_bipartite_graphs) or the [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem), and has efficient algorithms such as the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).